# Как отключить браузерные сообщения у input о необходимости заполнить поле к которому присвоено required?

Tags: html, css, input, валидация

Настроил свои сообщения, а вместе с ними вылезают и у Chrome, наверно и у других браузеров тоже

Comment: Вопрос конкретно напишите с примерами

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, вопрос и так понятен.

Comment: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/building-html5-form-validation-bubble-replacements/ - пробовал так?

Comment: @Qwertiy этим методом отключаются сообщения, но и мои тоже. Просто не происходит отправка, если поля не заполнены, но сообщения все не появляются

Answer (score 1):

Используй атрибут `novalidate` формы:

```css
form { margin-bottom: 1em; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input required>
  <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>

<form novalidate>
  <input required>
  <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

Comment: Если `novalidate` использовать тогда и мои сообщения не будут появляться

Comment: по крайней мере при нажатии на submit. Наверно надо их как-то привязать к самой этой кнопке

Comment: @АлександрТимофеев, ну правильно, ты валидацию формы браузером отключаешь, делаешь вместо неё собственную и показываешь сообщения сам.